# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

## Having some problems in deploying rails app on heroku  when i am running `git push heroku master`

it says 
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets' with type 'application/javascript'

here is the stacktrace:

```
>remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'bootstrap-sprockets' with type 'application/javascript'
remote:        Checked in these paths:
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/app/assets/config
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/app/assets/images
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/app/assets/javascripts
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/app/assets/stylesheets
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.1.4/lib/assets/compiled
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.1.4/lib/assets/compiled
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.3/lib/assets/javascripts
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/node_modules
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:65:in `resolve!'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:399:in `resolve'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:207:in `process_require_directive'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:180:in `block in process_directives'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:83:in `_call'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_db1edd81ba80d924bf7071c38f395c26/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
```

## here is my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tre
```

## here is my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

## here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'twitter'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
  gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

i am using  ruby 2.4.2p198 , Rails 5.1.4

Anybody who might know what the issue is? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

must be on production group  too.